# Update to EE to 2.9 Effected Store Dynamic Parameters & Pagination

Tags: expresso-store, pagination, dynamic, parameters

We recently updated a project from August of 2014 to use EE 2.9 and Store 2.5 which impacted the site's sorting feature and pagination; both no longer work now.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
{exp:store:search channel="products" limit="9" dynamic="yes" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic_parameters="limit|orderby" search_id="{segment_3}" paginate="top"}
                    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" form_class="form-horizontal" return="store/shopping-cart"}

                    {paginate}
                    <div class="page-numbers">
                    {pagination_links}
                    {previous_page}
                       <div class="previous"><a href="{pagination_url}">< Previous</a></div>
                    {/previous_page}
                    {first_page}
                        <div class="num{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}{if current_page}-one{if:else}-two{/if}{/exp:ifelse}"><a href="{pagination_url}">1</a></div>
                    {/first_page}
                    {page}
                        <div class="num{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}{if current_page}-one{if:else}-two{/if}{/exp:ifelse}"><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></div>
                    {/page}
                    {next_page}
                        <div class="next"><a href="{pagination_url}">Next ></a></div>
                    {/next_page}

                    {last_page}
                        <div class="previous" style="margin-left:10px;"><a href="{pagination_url}">Last Page</a></div>
                    {/last_page}
                    {/pagination_links}
                    </div>
                    {/paginate}
                    {/exp:store:product} 
                    {/exp:store:search}


                    <div class="pagination-container">
                        <div class="left">

                        {exp:ifelse parse="inward"} 

                           {if last_segment =="all"}
                            {exp:entries_number channel="products" category_group="1"}
                            {entries_number} Item(s)
                            {/exp:entries_number}

                            {if:elseif last_segment =="segment_3"}
                            {exp:entries_number channel="products" category_group="1" category="{last_segment_category_id}"}
                            {entries_number} Item(s)
                            {/exp:entries_number}

                            {if:elseif segment_2 =="new"}
                            {exp:store:search channel="products" search_id="{segment_3}"}
                             {if count == 1}
                              {total_results} Item{if total_results > 1}s{/if}
                             {/if}
                            {/exp:store:search}

                            {if:else}
                            {exp:entries_number channel="products" category_group="1" category="{last_segment_category_id}"}
                            {entries_number} Item(s)
                            {/exp:entries_number}
                            {/if}

                         {/exp:ifelse}

                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                        {exp:dynamo:form return="products/new" search_id="{segment_3}" id="options_form"}
                            <p>Show <select class="form_option" name="limit">
                            <option value="9" {if limit == 9} selected="selected"{/if}> 9 </option> 
                            <option value="18" {if limit == 18} selected="selected"{/if}> 18 </option> 
                            <option value="27" {if limit == 27} selected="selected"{/if}> 27 </option>
                            </select> 
                            per page</p>
                            <p>Sort by <select class="form_option" name="orderby"> 
                            <option value="title" {if orderby == 'title'} selected="selected"{/if}> Name </option> 
                            <option value="price" {if orderby == 'price'} selected="selected"{/if}> Price </option>
                            </select> </p>
                            <p>Min: <select class="form_option" name="search:price:min"> 
                            <option value="0" {if search:price:min == '0'} selected="selected"{/if}> 0 </option> 
                            <option value="100" {if search:price:min == '100'} selected="selected"{/if}> 100 </option>
                            <option value="200" {if search:price:min == '200'} selected="selected"{/if}> 200 </option>
                            <option value="300" {if search:price:min == '300'} selected="selected"{/if}> 300 </option>
                            <option value="400" {if search:price:min == '400'} selected="selected"{/if}> 400 </option>
                            <option value="400" {if search:price:min == '500'} selected="selected"{/if}> 500 </option>
                            </select></p>
                            <p>Max: <select class="form_option" name="search:price:max"> 
                            <option value="1000" {if search:price:max == '1000'} selected="selected"{/if}> 1,000 </option> 
                            <option value="500" {if search:price:max == '500'} selected="selected"{/if}> 500 </option>
                            <option value="400" {if search:price:max == '400'} selected="selected"{/if}> 400 </option>
                            <option value="300" {if search:price:max == '300'} selected="selected"{/if}> 300 </option>
                            <option value="200" {if search:price:max == '200'} selected="selected"{/if}> 200 </option>
                            <option value="100" {if search:price:max == '100'} selected="selected"{/if}> 100 </option>
                            </select>
                            </p> 
                        {/exp:dynamo:form}
```

We saw this on EE's site: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/dynamic_parameters.html#13604  Does anyone know how this impacts pagination?

Comment: "Both no longer work" - can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, when someone selects an option it no longer filters any information.  http://goo.gl/OQxIYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic filtering was altered in the updates and the combination no longer functioned.  Integration of MySQL Queries was needed to create the desired result.